# Advice on Canadian payment gateway for VirtueMart (Joomla!)?

Tags: joomla, payment-gateway, virtuemart, payment-processing

I'm developing a shopping cart system for a client using Joomla! 1.5 and VirtueMart and am in the market for a payment gateway provider. That said, I have a couple of unique requests:

- Not PayPal -- The client sells tobacco accessories, which is against PayPal ToS.
- Allows the sale of tobacco accessories/products -- my client primarily sells glass pipes and waterpipes for tobacco use only. If there's a chance a payment provider will classify these as "paraphernalia" or other things contravening their ToS, I'd prefer to avoid inquiring only to be told I can't use their service. This is why Google Checkout isn't an option, btw.
- Good support for VirtueMart -- I've never really programmed a payment module before, so easy of integration with VirtueMart is important.

I'm waiting on a response from PsiGate, though I'm leaning towards Pivotal Payments given the client already uses that company for processing in-store transactions. That said, Pivotal seems to have pretty poor support for VirtueMart -- I can only find a forum post about their payment module, and it seems the people in that thread were having a really hard time implementing it.

Epic-level gratefulness for anyone with suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VM has very good support to Authorize.net. I have also recently implemented a Link Point (now called First Data) payment module. There is a really good step by step for the Link Point module that worked perfectly for me on VM 1.1.5 here - http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=35263.msg107934#msg107934